# Why does my text with html tags doesn't show right when I use javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this text :

```
 <p class="rtejustify">No &acirc;mbito do Programa de Literacia Estat&iacute;stica promovido pela Biblioteca, a terceira sess&atilde;o decorrer&aacute; no dia 28, entre as 14h30 e as 17h00, na Sala EC-101 (STI), tendo como recurso estat&iacute;stico o Portal do Eurostat.</p>
```

that if i use it like this:

```
<div class="corpo">     
    <p class="rtejustify">No &acirc;mbito do Programa de Literacia Estat&iacute;stica promovido pela Biblioteca, a terceira sess&atilde;o decorrer&aacute; no dia 28, entre as 14h30 e as 17h00, na Sala EC-101 (STI), tendo como recurso estat&iacute;stico o Portal do Eurostat.</p>
```

shows up correct in the html page...
Like this :

> No âmbito do Programa de Literacia Estatística promovido , a terceira sessão decorrerá no  tendo como recurso estatístico o Portal do Eurostat.

but i if get the same code in a js function and put it on a variable, when i open the html file the html tags are also presented...

Example:
[click to test](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ruqfgkrr/)

```js
var texto= "<p class="rtejustify">No &acirc;mbito do Programa de Literacia Estat&iacute;stica promovido pela Biblioteca, a terceira sess&atilde;o decorrer&aacute; no dia 28, entre as 14h30 e as 17h00, na Sala EC-101 (STI), tendo como recurso estat&iacute;stico o Portal do Eurostat.</p>";
$(".corpo").text(texto);
```

```css
.corpo
{
    background-color:#000066 ;
    opacity: 0.8;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    width:1000px;
    height:380px;
    position:fixed;  
    z-index:3;
    overflow: scroll;
    color:white;      
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:20px;
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:bold;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="corpo">     
        <p class="rtejustify">No &acirc;mbito do Programa de Literacia Estat&iacute;stica promovido pela Biblioteca, a terceira sess&atilde;o decorrer&aacute; no dia 28, entre as 14h30 e as 17h00, na Sala EC-101 (STI), tendo como recurso estat&iacute;stico o Portal do Eurostat.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to use jQuery `.html()` instead of `.text()` http://fiddle.jshell.net/ruqfgkrr/1/

Comment: Also you have error in your js if you want to use double quotes inside double quotes you need to escape them or use single quote.

Comment: Your Javascript code has syntax errors. You're using double quotes as both the string delimiter and the delimiter around the `class` attribute.

Comment: @jcubic that .html() worked thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of the `text` function, use the `html` function.
http://api.jquery.com/html/

It is strange that my browser has the same behaviour for `text` and `html`, but basically, if you're using html: use `html`, otherwise use `text`.

Using Opera on Mac OS X
`Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36 OPR/29.0.1795.47` It is maybe a bug in Opera or by (flawed) design.

Comment: His fiddle isn't running the Javascript at all, because of the quoting problem, so you're seeing the original HTML.

Comment: thank you, i used html() insted of text and it worked

Comment: Ah, must've slipped past my eyes. @Ana could you mark this as the solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
    var texto= "<p class='rtejustify'>No &acirc;mbito do Programa de Literacia Estat&iacute;stica promovido pela Biblioteca, a terceira sess&atilde;o decorrer&aacute; no dia 28, entre as 14h30 e as 17h00, na Sala EC-101 (STI), tendo como recurso estat&iacute;stico o Portal do Eurostat.</p>";
$(".corpo").html(texto);
```

Try this code..

@Barmar :
You should have used html() instead of text(). And You have used doublequotes inside the javascript variable **texto**. The classname **rtejustify** should be in placed between singlequotes.

Comment: Please explain what you changed, don't just dump code.

Answer (score 0):

## method 1

insted use javascript direct function like this: `document.getElemenstByClassName('corpo')[0].innerHTML="your text"`

## method 2

`document.getElemenstByClassName('corpo')[0].appendChild(document.createTextNode("your text"))` this one is different from the above one in the aspect that it prints all the tag and everything.

## method 3

```
document.getElemenstByClassName('corpo')[0].innerHTML= document.getElemenstByClassName('corpo')[0].value+ "your text"
```

this way allows us to use the tags.

method 2 and method 3 is like usign Jquery `$(".corpo").text(texto);` and `$(".corpo").html(texto);`  respectively.(please not that i don't think it is the implementation of Jquery).

The difference lies between these two method is that the Ist creates a Node what that mean Javascript treates everything as a String it dont differentiates between `<p>` and `p` i.e. tags and simple text where as `innerHTML` just put the things in between the double quotes in an element becauses of this we can take the advantages of tags there.

This technique is used in Firefox. There in `textarea` everyline you enter it is put into the `textarea` tag as a text Node. You can see this your self in Console.

[See working example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ruqfgkrr/2/)

Comment: Why not post it here as a stack snippet instead of jsfiddle?

Comment: This doesn't work the same, because it only updates the first element with the class, the jQuery code updates all of them.

Comment: ohh come on, this is only a shortest way to do this, and if you want other methods then wait...

Comment: One of the advantages of using jQuery is you don't have to write out loops to process all the elements that match a selection. What's the point of suggesting an alternative when it's not as easy to use?

Comment: Especially when it's so simple to just change `.text` to `.html` in the original code to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with the below code.

```
var texto= "<p class='rtejustify'>No &acirc;mbito do Programa de Literacia Estat&iacute;stica promovido pela Biblioteca, a terceira sess&atilde;o decorrer&aacute; no dia 28, entre as 14h30 e as 17h00, na Sala EC-101 (STI), tendo como recurso estat&iacute;stico o Portal do Eurostat.</p>";
$(".corpo").text(texto);
```